# What does the formula $y =\sqrt{R^2-(x - a)^2} + b$ represent?

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm reading a Calculus book that mentions the formula $y =\sqrt{R^2-(x - a)^2} + b$ along with the definition of a circle formula, $(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = R^2$. It seems using these formulas to approximate a curve.

Can anyone tell me what $y =\sqrt{R^2-(x - a)^2} + b$ is supposed to represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have "halfway" solved for $y$ in the equation of the circle.  At some point you get
$$
(y-b)^2 = R^2 - (x-a)^2.
$$
This means that 
$$
y-b =\pm \sqrt{R^2 - (x-a)^2}
$$
or
$$
y =\pm \sqrt{R^2 - (x-a)^2} +b.
$$
By choosing only one of the square roots you get one half of circle:  the positive roots give the top half, the negative roots the bottom.

So, by solving for $y$ and choosing the positive square root, you have the equation for the top half of the circle. (Or, said differently, a function of $x$ mapping out the top half of the circle.)

Comment: Thank you! This helps!